# URL for installing Drupal

Tags: url, drupal, installation, manual

I am trying to install Drupal using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/drupal/drupal_installation.htm) manual.

I am stuck at the following step:

> Open your browser and navigate to your Drupal file path, you will see the first Drupal installer screen as shown in the following image. In our case the path is **localhost/< Your_drupal_folder >**. Select the Standard option and click Save and continue.

I downloaded the Drupal folder:
[image]

Now I copy and paste the path to Drupal folder into Chrome, and nothing happens, I am not presented with the installation window:
[image]

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you need a web server and a database with PHP. You should look at MAMP or WAMP depending if you are using Mac or Windows. A quick Search should put you on the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installation of Drupal on you local machine, you'll have to install local webserver on your system i.e. XAMPP. You can download it here i.e. https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Follow these steps :

**Step 1 : Start XAMPP control Panel**

Once, you'll install this. you'll get a control panel of XAMPP software and start two modules i.e. Apache & MySql.
For reference, please check this screen shot i.e.

[image]

**Step 2 : Place your Drupal Setup in Xampp**

You'll get a xampp folder in you C drive. Now, you have to place your extracted drupal setup in **htdocs** folder at this path i.e. **C:\xampp\htdocs** and rename folder with **drupaltest**.

For reference, please check this screen shot i.e.

[image]

**Step 3 : Create Database**

Now, we have to create DB in PHPmyadmin i.e. http://localhost/phpmyadmin
Default credentials of PHPMYADMIN are username : **root** & Password : EMPTY/NOTHING

**Step 4 : Run Drupal**

Now you have to run Drupal at this path i.e. http://localhost/drupaltest 
Follow this link i.e. https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/install-run.html

For more technical articles, have a look at http://etutorialz.com

Now, your drupal site is ready.