# How can I run the Drupal project

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, setup-project

I almost do not know Drupal at all, but I have a project which was created with Drupal.

I setup the Drupal locally. And read a few of the tutorials from over [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/drupal/). I read about Menu, Block, Regions, Themes and Layouts, but that did not help me to understand how to run the existing Drupal project.

Here, by the way is the screenshot of the project:

[image]

So, I would be grateful if someone explained me how to run a Drupal project or provided me a link to the guide on how to do it.

I am not intended to learn the Drupal in depth or develop something in it. I want just to made minor changed to the existing project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very broad and I'm almost sure that it be will down voted and closed, but I'll try to help before that happens. :)

So, to run drupal (or any similar php based) project you must have web server with support for PHP running and this code inside some web root directory defined in web server settings file. You'll also need mysql server running. Easiest way (for local experimenting/development) would be running WAMP server or some similar solution:
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Then, when you set up web server and your site url, when you visit it for the first time Drupal will recognize that project has to be set yet and lead you trough set of forms for setting up the project. At end you will have functional site.

If you face any problem please be more specific what the problem is.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742674/deprecated-function-the-each-function-is-deprecated-in-drupal) I got a more specific question. Thank you. (y)

Answer (score 1):

We already have the same question here i.e. [URL for installing Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641434/url-for-installing-drupal/53645101)

Here is detailed answer of this question i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645101/2089994

For more technical articles, have a look at http://etutorialz.com

Comment: That is a different question. That question is about installing the Drupal to the system. But in case Drupal should be installed separately for each Drupal project, then your answer is clear. So, should Drupal be installed for each project individually? Thank you.