# Deprecated function: The each() function is deprecated in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, installation, updates, setup-project

I am trying to run a Drupal project.

And I am getting the following error:

> No active batch.
>   Deprecated function: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in menu_set_active_trail() (line 2405 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcLegacyLexicon\fiveDayDiscovery\includes\menu.inc).

Then I am selecting all the files and click download these updates.

After that I am getting the following error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /mmcLegacyLexicon/fiveDayDiscovery/batch?id=6&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcLegacyLexicon\fiveDayDiscovery\modules\system\system.tar.inc on line 717

[image]

[image]

What can I do about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal version 7.61 supports PHP version 7.2. You are using Drupal version 7.60.

Source: [Drupal release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.61)

Comment: Should I uninstall the current Drupal version and install the Drupal 7.61 ?

Comment: No, just run the updates. That will solve compatibility for Drupal core, but if you face some issues with contrib modules you'll have to solve each one separately.